# Фикс обхода максимального и минимального заданного интервала в DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть следующий конвертер:

```
public class DatePickerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

И вот такой вот xaml:

```
<DatePicker 
    DisplayDateStart="{Binding Source={StaticResource datePickerConverter}, Path=., Converter={StaticResource datePickerConverter}}"
    DisplayDateEnd = "{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, Path=.}">
</DatePicker>
```

И вроде бы всё нормально, нужный интервал готов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, если вручную в `DatePicker` вписать рандомную дату, то сразу же появляется новый интервал которого не должно быть в принципе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как данный баг устранить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас странная привязка к конвертеру. Привязка должна быть к свойству, свойство передается в аргумент конвертера.

Конвертер должен выглядеть вот так, если уж решили его делать, хотя я бы обошелся дополнительным свойством.

```
public class DatePickerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((DateTime)value).AddDays(-3);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Я бы, кстати, это `-3` унес в разметку и передавал бы как `ConverterParameter` из XAML привязки. Тогда не придется переписывать конвертер, если появится потребность разные интервалы для разных пикеров задавать.

Затем создать свойство во вьюмодели для выбранной даты

```
public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
```

И тогда получится вот такая верстка

```xml
<DatePicker
    DisplayDateStart="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}, Converter={StaticResource datePickerConverter}, Mode=OneTime}"
    DisplayDateEnd="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}, Mode=OneTime}"
    SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

То есть просто выключить текстовый ввод. Пользователю только останется выбрать дату.

---

В этом плане мне нравится WinUI 3 (Windows App SDK), там то же самое можно получить вот таким образом, то есть `CalendarDatePicker` не позволяет текстовый ввод по умолчанию, да и выглядит поприкольнее.

```xml
<CalendarDatePicker MinDate="{x:Bind sys:DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3)}" 
                    MaxDate="{x:Bind sys:DateTime.Today}"
                    Date="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жаль, что в остальном там не все так прикольно, и WPF пока выглядит в разы мощнее.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! А можете показать как бы сделали вы Converter?

Comment: @Aarnihauta да просто свойство `public DateTime StartDate => DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3);` и привязаться к нему, выкинув конвертер.